# The ports always returns 0 when I run suricata based dpdk

Tags: dpdk, suricata

I have installed DPDK-19.11.1 LTS successfully as follows：

[image]

And the NIC I have bound as follows:

[image]

If I run an example (`dpdk/dpdk-stable-19.11.3/examples/skeleton/build/basicfwd`)，the function `rte_eth_dev_count_avail()` returns the ports I bound with `dpdk-devbind.py`.

[image]

I have also installed [Suricata-4.1.4](https://github.com/vipinpv85/DPDK_SURICATA-4_1_1) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS，but when I run suricata，the dpdk ports always returns 0:

[image]

So I want to know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: rejected twice for the edit in the question (to reflect the real) problem. not sure, how to make this clear. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26850782

Comment: The issue faced is understood and the solution suggested is accepted by Author as it solves the problem. Since the `problem statement is not correct`, edited the same. But https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405122/volker-siegel and https://stackoverflow.com/users/51242/bryan has difference in opinion stating `This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the update in the ticket https://github.com/vipinpv85/DPDK_SURICATA-4_1_1/issues/11, the solution is already shared as `can you please check if you are using the latest version? If yes please add support for 1G Intel NIC in your environment and update ASAP`

hence please add the missing PMD for your use case.

[EDIT-2] the DPDK PMD used for 1G Intel NIC is `rte_pmd_e1000`

[EDIT-3] had live debug, show case the change to be added for Makfile. Tested and it works

Comment: Yes, the version is the latest. What can I do to add supoort for 1G Inter NIC and add the missing PMD in Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed DPDK-19.11.1 and run the examples successfully，includes skeleton/build/basicfwd and testpmd。

Comment: @startkz if you opened github ticket, follow up in github.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for vipin's kind help. I have solve this problem successfully.

This is because in dpdk/suricata-4.1.4/src/Makefile, there is only support for i40e. So I add the -lrte_pmd_e1000 -Wl for i350.